# How to rename subset of filename of all files in directory?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

Have following files.

```bsh
test.tar.gz.part00
test.tar.gz.part01
test.tar.gz.part02
…
test.tar.gz.part99
```

Need to replace `.gz` by `.lz4`… ideally without using dependencies (such as `rename`) that do not ship with Debian.

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rename` for that.

`rename gz lz4 ./*part*`

Without `rename`:

`for file in ./*part*; do mv "$file" "${file//gz/lz4}"; done`

Comment: Your substitution works for the given names, but you're using `//` to replace _all_ instances of the string `gz` in the names, even though you only expect one (and it would mess up the name if there were many `gz` substrings). Safer in the more general case to glob on `*.gz.part*` and then do two substitutions to first remove the `.gz.part*` bit from the end and then insert `.lz4` followed the `.part*` bit from the original name. But if the names are simple as in the question, this does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

`rename` started out as very short `perl` example script in the 80s.

It's so short you can easily inline it into any script:

```
perl -e 'for (@ARGV) {
           $old = $_; rename $old, $_ if s/\.gz(\.part\d+)\Z/\.lz4$1/s
         }' -- *.gz.part*
```

Besides `perl`, `bash` is another language interpreter that is usually shipped by default on system based on Debian GNU/Linux (as that's the GNU shell). In that shell, you could do:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
for file in *.gz.part+([0123456789]); do
  mv -T -- "$file" "${file%.*.*}.lz4.${file##*.}"
done
```

As an equivalent.

Comment: Interesting contribution to the question… thanks Stéphane!